# Android app to connect to local IP device which is an accesspoint

Tags: android, sockets, android-wifi, esp8266

I have a hardware device, which acts as an Access point. 
I am able to disconnect mobile's wifi from router and then connect it to the wifi of the hardware device. 
Device Ip has a local IP and host a web server. 
I open a socket connection to device and ping it but until I turn off mobile data of my device, it's not able to connect to the local IP. 
Is there a way to communicate to the device (which is an Access point) without turning off the mobile data.

Code:- Below is class to create socket data

```
class ClientAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            Log.d("SocketProg", "Creating socket");
            String result = null;
            try {
                Log.d("SocketProg", String.valueOf(params[0]));
                Log.d("SocketProg", String.valueOf(params[1]));
                Log.d("SocketProg", String.valueOf(params[2]));
                //Create a client socket and define internet address and the port of the server
                Socket socket = new Socket(params[0],
                        Integer.parseInt(params[1]));
                //Get the input stream of the client socket
                InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                //Get the output stream of the client socket
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                //Write data to the output stream of the client socket
                out.println(params[2]);
                out.flush();
                Log.d("SocketProg", "Sending data");
                //Buffer the data coming from the input stream
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is));
                //Read data in the input buffer
                result = br.readLine();
                //Close the client socket
                socket.close();
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which Android version?

Comment: `Below is class to create socket data`. Why did you post that code? What does it have to do with your question? And your question is different from the subject.

Comment: Code has everything to do with Question. I am asking that with this code, I  have to disconnect mobile data before connecting to local IP and asking Is there any alternative to connect to local IP without disconnecting from mobile data. Subject may be little bit unclear but It tells that I am trying to connect to local IP device and having problem with it.